# What did I do wrong? Header snet ahead?

Tags: php, deployment

I have those tree files:

**menulogged.php**

```
<?php
require_once('includes/helper/session.php');
require_once("includes/helper/initialize.php");
 if (!$session->is_logged_in())
    { Header("location:/public/userview/ctr_login.php"); }

  include_layout_template('admin_header.php');
?>
```

**ctr_login.php**

```
<?php
require_once("includes/helper/session.php");
    if($session->is_logged_in())
    {
      $mess='You are already logged in';
    }

?>
```

and **session.php**

```
<?php
// A class to help work with Sessions
// In our case, primarily to manage logging users in and out
class Session {

    private $logged_in=false;
    public $user_id;
    public $message;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_message();
        $this->check_login();
    }

  public function is_logged_in() {
    return $this->logged_in;
  }

    public function login($user) {
    // database should find user based on username/password
    if($user){
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
      $this->logged_in = true;
    }
  }

  public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($this->user_id);
    $this->logged_in = false;
  }



$session = new Session();
$message = $session->message();

?>
```

For some reason since I am not logged in I get to the login controller and then I get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(includes/helper/initialize.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/40/7141640/html/public/userview/ctr_login.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/helper/initialize.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/40/7141640/html/public/userview/ctr_login.php on line 2
```

I can not believe I am having so many issues with deploying the website I just made. I thought in an hour at most it would be done, but apparently only a person that never made a website would believe that. I looked at the code for at least an hour and I can't figure it out. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**
I noticed that no matter which two files I call, on the first file the include works fine, and on the second one it can't find the file.

Comment: could you please provide the absolute paths to the files? It looks like your php include-path is not set up correctly

Comment: I didn't set it up. Where should I set it up, and how?

Comment: as I wrote in my answer: Use set_include_path (http://de2.php.net/set_include_path)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to include a file that doesn't exist, `initialize.php`. Make sure your include path is set up correctly, and that the paths you type in are correct.

Comment: no, actually teh file exists. if you notice in the menulogged file I call it too, and it finds it just fine. That's what I just can't understand.

Comment: `Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/helper/initialize.php'`, and the warning, means exactly that the file does not exist. Please double check carefully, including spelling and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell PHP where to look for include files. By default, PHP will look in the same directory where the script that is being run is resident and obviously in /usr/local/php5/lib/php. You are looking for includes/helper/initialize.php. Make sure, the "includes" folder is in the same directory as the file ctr_login.php OR that the include path is set correctly. (set_include_path()).

Comment: But then why does it call it just fine in menulogged, and it doesn't call it in ctr_login. Both files are in the same folder. Can you please be more explicit on how to set the include path?

Comment: ok, if they are in the same folder, the failure has to be somewhere else. In which order are these files included? Which file do you access in your internet browser?

Comment: menulogged.php it's the first one that is accessed

Comment: ok... so it redirects to the other file and there the error occurs. From your public folder... where is the "includes" directory? is it public/includes? or is it public/userview/includes?

Comment: both directories are in the root: includes and public ; public has public/userview/ctr.login and includes contains teh other file i also notices that no matter what two pages i call that have require_once(../initialize.php) for the second file it gives the exact error

Comment: do you browse the first file directly or is it included by another script? The problem is, that PHP does not know WHERE the includes directory is... there is no such thing as a root as long you don't specify it by prepending a slash to the path...

Comment: it's sent as a header from idex php, so practicly i redirect to it from there.

Comment: you really should not do all this stuff with header('Location...');... it's not only really hard to debug but also really slow compared to the result you could get by just including the right files at the right time... looks for me like a big chaos... nevertheless... try using require_once ('../../includes/helper/initialize.php') in your 2nd file. (Sorry guys... :D )

Comment: it doesn't work, because i have to go back to the menulogin file and then it messes up again, and if i call the include with the slashes in the menuloggin, it doesn't find it to start with.

Comment: include this line in all your files... it's ugly but it will work...

set_include_path("/home/content/40/7141640/html/:/usr/local/php5/lib/php");

Answer (score 0):

Double-check if there are space characters before the `<?php` in each included file. This could cause the headers to be sent out.

Comment: no, there are no spaces. i checked many times, and double-checked just now

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not very sure though, but could you try to change the header syntax into:

```
header("Location: /public/userview/ctr_login.php");
```

Also try to use the the absolute path (e.g. www.example.com/userview/ctr_login.php) rather than relative path.

Hope it could help, :)